# Обработка Excel файлов в Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Есть Excel файл, например:

| Исходное | Вычисляемое |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 28 |
| 45 |  |
| 12 | 17 |
| 78 |  |

Нужно найти пустые значения в Вычисляемом столбце, взять по строке значение из Исходного столбца, применить к нему функцию и записать результат в Вычисляемое.

Использую Python для этого. Очень долго гуглил. Загружать файл я научился. Но вот как с загруженными данными работать... Пришел к тому, что надо юзать Pandas. Но я никак не могу понять, как пройтись в цикле по определенному столбцу и совершить те действия, что я описал выше.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать. Может быть и не Pandas вовсе юзать?

Comment: Что-то типа такого будет в пандасе `mask = df['Вычисляемое'].isnan(); df.loc[mask, 'Вычисляемое'] = df.loc[mask, 'Исходное'].apply(функция)`

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось сделать вот так:

```
import pandas as pd

def my_function():
    #тут что-то выполняется
    return(результат_выполнения)

cols = [0, 1]
df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx', usecols=cols)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isna(row['Вычисляемое']):
        df['Вычисляемое'][i] = my_function(df['Исходное'][i])
```

Работает, но мне кажется, что при большом кол-ве данных будет выполняться долго. Есть советы по оптимизации? Пример от крейзи эльфа будет правильнее? Там без цикла даже))